# Bigger headline numbers without changing the height of the headline

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, scaling

I have made the section numbers in the headlines appear in the margin with this code

```
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+7mm+\hoffset\relax}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{2}\bfseries\color{darkmagenta}}
  {\llap{\hspace*{-\mylen}\thesection\hfill}}{0em}{}
```

and I can make the numbers smaller by putting for example `\tiny` into the last line. However I can not make them bigger by for example `\large` in there instead.

So how do I make the *section numbers*

- *bigger* (perhaps twice as big)
- with there *top the same* place (i.e. they goes under the floor of the line)
- *without changing the overall hight* of the headline (i.e. the lines above and under will be placed the same as before)?

Working example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+7mm+\hoffset\relax}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{2}\bfseries}
  {\llap{\hspace*{-\mylen}\thesection\hfill}}{0em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{A headline}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your code so it can be compiled.

Comment: Yes, of cause :-)

Answer (score 1):

Below I've placed the numbering inside a number of boxes to move it into position, as well as scaling it `3` times larger than what it usually is. Movement down and removal of any vertical adjustment is achieved using `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{..}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor,graphicx,lipsum}
\colorlet{darkmagenta}{black!30!magenta}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+7mm+\hoffset\relax}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{darkmagenta}}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \makebox[\mylen][l]{%
      \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.6\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \scalebox{3}{\thesection}}}}}{0em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```